# Angular 2. Avoid missed selector error

Tags: angular

How do I can avoid error if the selector is missed on current page?
For example I have some component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'SomeDirrective',
    template: `<h1>Out</h1>`
})
```

and if the page has

```
<SomeDirrective>Loading...</SomeDirrective>
```

then all is fine, but I don't want to have this "SomeDirrective" on each page and if this element is missed, A2 will generate errors:

*"The selector "SomeDirrective" did not match any elements"*

Which part should be changed or howto supress error?

Comment: Don't bootstrap the application if you don't have a matching selector.

Comment: So I suppose it should be something like that:
if(document.getElementsByTagName('SomeDirrective').length > 0 )
System.import.......

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Comment: Thank you.
Solved.